# Unable to find a Dynamics CRM 2011 installer

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I've recently acquired a new client, they are using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and I need to replicate their working environment on my server.
I seem unable to find a download link for the server setup, the official Microsoft download center gives 404, and all other sources I've found on the web aren't working (the new Partner Center doesn't provide a download for the 2011 version).
Does anyone know where I can find a working installer?
Thanks

Comment: Probably it’s sunset already. Also reach out to Dynamics community, anyone may have backup in drives.

Comment: Thank you Arun i'll try right now...I didn't think about It :)

Comment: any luck with the community?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I found some other versions via Visual Studio Subscription but not the 2011....thank you anyway!